# Hide and display HTML elements based on what was chosen in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

My website is created in ASP classic - VBScript (not my choice and is a language I've not had experience with before this). I'm trying to create a webpage where in it: A dropdown menu reveals an additional dropdown based on what was selected in the first one. I'm trying to use a javascript function to achieve this.

Example:

In the first dropdown the user chooses ice cream or crisps.
Based on what the user selects another dropdown gives the choice of flavour.

Ice cream: vanilla, chocolate, mint.
Crisps: ready salted, cheese & onion, salt & vinegar.

This is what my code currently looks like:

**HTML**

```
<select id="food" onchange="fctCheck(this.value)">
    <option value="">Choose an item</option>
    <option value="icecream">Ice cream</option>
    <option value="crisps">Crisps</option>
</select>  


<select id="icecream" style="display:none">
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="mint">Mint</option>
</select>  


<select id="crisps" style="display:none">
    <option value="readysalted">Ready Salted</option>
    <option value="cheeseandonion">Cheese and Onion</option>
    <option value="saltandvinegar">Salt and Vinegar</option>
</select>
```

.

**javascript**

```
function fctCheck(food)
    {
    if (food == "")
        {document.getElementById(food).style.display = "none";}
    else
        {document.getElementById(food).style.display = "block";}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned by st3inn `this.value` is absolutely fine - there is just the typo by `document.getElement==>B<==yId`.

But your code has the disadvantage, that a user could select both options and so both sub-selections would be visible.

**You could avoid this by first hiding all sub-selections before showing the one for the selected item.** This could be done that way (via the addiotional name-attribute, or, if you choose to work with jQuery you could do something more sophisticated instead):

[Example (with comments) on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49UKH/2/)

Javascript:

```
function fctCheck(food) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByName("subselector");
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById(food).style.display = "block";
    }
```

HTML:

```
<select id="food"onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
    <option value="">Choose an item</option>
    <option value="icecream">Ice cream</option>
    <option value="crisps">Crisps</option>
</select>  


<select id="icecream" name="subselector" style="display:none">
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="mint">Mint</option>
</select>  


<select id="crisps" name="subselector" style="display:none">
    <option value="readysalted">Ready Salted</option>
    <option value="cheeseandonion">Cheese and Onion</option>
    <option value="saltandvinegar">Salt and Vinegar</option>
</select>
```

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: Thanks Florian, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `option` value instead:

```
fctCheck(this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ].value)
```

`this.options` is collection of `<option>` elements inside your current `<select>`, and `this.options.selectedIndex` is integer value that show what option currently selected.

BTW you have an typo in your code:

```
document.getElementbyId
```

should be

```
document.getElementById
```

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dCTd6/)

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo - post has been edited.

Comment: Had a look at your jsFiddle demo. Is there a way to re-hide elements. e.g. if I choose crisps but then change my mind to ice cream is it possible to hide the crisps dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo.

```
function fctCheck(food)
{
    if (food == "") {
        document.getElementById(food).style.display = "none";}
    } else {
        document.getElementById(food).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

should work.

```
this.value
```

is equivalent to

```
this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value
```